# mysql database won't allow tcp connections on localhost at the default port

Tags: mysql, tcp, mysql-connection

Trying to connect to a database with a c++ program. I am using the [mysqlcppconnector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/) with the connection strings `tcp://localhost:3306` and `tcp://127.0.0.1:3306`. The program works on my local machine, but when I try to run it on my remote ubuntu server after ssh'ing in, it complains:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'sql::SQLException'
  what():  Unknown MySQL server host 'tcp' (2)
```

I'm just trying to connect on localhost, at the default port 3306. I can also connect manually by typing in `mysql -u root -p` and just logging in that way.

After logging in to my database with `mysql -u root -p`, I can type `show variables;` and indeed I see `skip-networking` set to "OFF".

MySQL is listening on the network:

```
netstat -a | grep mysql
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     20025    /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Is there some configuration that I forgot to change? What does the "(2)" mean?

Comment: @Christopher ```root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01:~# netstat -a | grep mysql
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     20025    /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Comment: Check the firewall setting too ;)

Comment: @mariaczi on the server? how would I bet able to ssh in then?

Comment: Is [How to connect mySQL database using C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16424828/2344631) any help?

Comment: @roaima my code resembles that. But I'm reasonably sure it already works--I have successfully ran the program on my local machine. It connects to a database and writes to it. This error only pops up when I try to run it on my server. I was thinking it's either some default configuration that digital ocean  has, or some path that was hardcoded that changes...I'm not sure what it could even be.

Comment: It looks like it's trying to resolve the non-existent hostname `tcp`.  are you sure that's a valid URL protocol type or connection string for your mysql library?  try it without the `tcp://`, i.e. as just `127.0.0.1` or `127.0.0.1:3306`.     BTW, mysql has **always** been weird about localhost connections - it takes it upon itself to silently convert tcp connections to localhost into unix domain socket connections....but I don't think that's what's happening here.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for the suggestions. I fixed it by reinstalling mysqlcppconnector (not by changing the c++ code). I started suspecting it was something build-related, so I asked about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58550337/why-is-mysql-refusing-local-connections/58559824#58559824).

A few notes on the differences between the two installations: instead of using 1.1.12, I reinstalled with the most recent edition; also, I didn't install by manually copying files around, I installed with

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlcppconn-dev
```

I don't know if this is a coincidence, but I also notice that clicking on "Looking for previous GA versions?" at the download page doesn't redirect you to version 1.1.12 anymore--it directs you to 1.1.13.

After this the program ran. Well, it did give me an error, but a different one, and the fix for this issue was pretty easy. For what it's worth, it was

```
Access Denied for User 'root'@'localhost'
```

I checked the permissions by typing `SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;`, saw that localhost didn't have mysql_native_password permissions (only auth_socket), so I changed that by doing

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'secret_password_here';
```

Hope this helps someone else--this was a strange one. Thanks everyone for the help, too.